# MySql error 1241 при UPDATE таблицы

Tags: mysql, база-данных, update

Нужно сделать update в таблице Vakansia. В таблице есть 5 записей, и нужно заменить в последней строке.
**У меня есть код для update:**

```
select * from Vakansia;
UPDATE `Vakansia` SET `nazva_pidpryemstva`='SoftServe' WHERE vakansia_id=5;
```

**Записи в таблице Vakansia:**

```
use Birzha_Praci_Remake;
select * from Vakansia;

insert into Vakansia (nazva_pidpryemstva, posada, dohid, vymogy_id) values ('EPAM', 'Computer scientist', 50000, 1);
insert into Vakansia (nazva_pidpryemstva, posada, dohid, vymogy_id) values ('Library', 'Librarian', 5000, 2);
insert into Vakansia (nazva_pidpryemstva, posada, dohid, vymogy_id) values ('SoftServe', 'Junior FrontEnd', 10000, 3);
insert into Vakansia (nazva_pidpryemstva, posada, dohid, vymogy_id) values ('Zhek', 'Cleaner', 3000, 4);
insert into Vakansia (nazva_pidpryemstva, posada, dohid, vymogy_id) values ('EPAM', 'Senior BackEnd', 45000, 5);
```

> Но при запуске есть error 1241. Error Code: 1241. Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Сам update написан правильно и я не понимаю в чем проблема

**Код создания всех 5 таблиц и бд:**

```
create database Birzha_Praci_Remake;

use Birzha_Praci_Remake;

create table Dodumovy (
    dodumovy_id int not null auto_increment,
    spysok_inozemnyh_mov text,
    vminnya_pracuvaty_za_pk varchar(6),
    stazh_za_fahom int,
    primary key(dodumovy_id)
);

create table Osvita (
    osvita_id int not null auto_increment,
    riven_osvity varchar (255),
    specialnist varchar (255),
    primary key(osvita_id)
);

create table Vymogy (
    vymogy_id int not null auto_increment,
    vik int,
    stat varchar (255),
    osvita_id int not null,
    foreign key(osvita_id) references Osvita(osvita_id),
    dodumovy_id int not null,
    foreign key(dodumovy_id) references Dodumovy(dodumovy_id),
    primary key(vymogy_id)
);

create table Vakansia (
    vakansia_id int not null auto_increment,
    nazva_pidpryemstva varchar (255),
    posada varchar (255),
    dohid int,
    primary key(vakansia_id),
    vymogy_id int not null,
    foreign key(vymogy_id) references Vymogy(vymogy_id)
);

create table Zarplata_Company(
    id_vakansii int not null auto_increment,
    info varchar(255),
    Company varchar(255),
    Zarplata int,
    old_info varchar(255),
    primary key(id_vakansii)
);
```

*Я выключил safe_updates в настройках mysql workbench.*

---

*Пробовал переделать запрос.*

---

*Если делать select по vakansia_id = 5, то оно показывает то что надо и нету никаких ерроров, но если я хочу сделать update по vakansia_id = 5, то есть error 1241.*

---

*Искал инфу в поисковике, сидел на разных форумах но так ничего и не нашел.*

---

*Не спорю, может я плохо искал, но никак не могу пофиксить этот error.*

---

*Делал много манипуляций но ничего не помогло и error 1241 так и остался.*

---

**Может кто знает что с этим делать?**

Comment: *при запуске есть error 1241. Error Code: 1241. Operand should contain 1 column(s)* Ни один из показанных запросов не может привести к этой ошибке. Смотри ошибки в триггерах.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Переделал тригер и все стало работать.